# I can't insert the image into the sdcard because it shows the error like

Tags: android, android-sdcard

[2013-01-23 22:49:52 - ddms] transfer error: Read-only file system

[2013-01-23 22:49:52] Failed to push selection: Read-only file system

Comment: How about posting some code to let us check it for mistakes causing this behaviour?

Comment: did you add permissions to write in the manifest file? share us your code'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just go to

`C:\Documents and Settings\<adminstrator>\.android\avd`

take `'properties'` of your avd folder (there is a folder for each of the avd's)

uncheck `'Read only'` -> OK

or

You can also give a try to this command in CMD, this will remount your SDCard.

```
c:\android-sdk\platform-tools\>adb remount
```

or

Add these permissions in Android manifest file for accessing Sd Card.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```